# Updating an Angular model from a mouse drag event

Tags: angularjs, digest

When I drag an element that I have drawn on a canvas, I would also like its live `x` and `y` coordinates to be shown outside of the canvas.

A quick description..

View:

```
//some HTML, including a canvas
{{xCoord}} </br>
{{yCoord}}
```

Directive: (`onDrag()` is called whenever the user clicks on and drags an object)

```
someCanvasObject.onDrag() {
    $scope.xCoord = canvasObject.x;
    $scope.yCoord = canvasObject.y;
    $scope.$digest();
}
```

However, when I use `$scope.$digest()` to change the outputted coordinates, I get an **"$apply is already in progress"** error because `$digest()` is called in quick succession by the drag rapidly modifying the coordinates.

Is there an alternative way to use `$digest()` that will not conflict when used rapidly in the way described above?

(I've been told `$$phase` is bad practice.)

Comment: Here's an example where you can spam $digest or $apply with no issue. http://jsbin.com/IbAfesur/22/edit You really should include a live demo so that your issue is more clear.. I can't see what the problem would be.

Comment: Thanks :) And apologies, I've updated the question so it's a bit more detailed. Please let me know if more's needed!

Comment: Like I said, you need a live demo.

Comment: The question seems clear to me. The essence of the problem is that you need to update the model on every callback, but throttle the calls to $digest.

Comment: try use $timeout service instead of scope.$apply

Comment: @noa that might fix it, but it seems like a workaround to something else that's broken. AFAIK, that error occurs when an attempt is made to start a $digest within the $digest process. The expected behavior here is to add $digests to the call stack, one after another, not inside of one another.

Comment: If you wanted one digest per call to onDrag, that would be simple enough, like this: `$timeout(function () { $scope.$digest(); });`

Answer (score 0):

You could start by trying something like this:

```
var timeout;
someCanvasObject.onDrag() {
    $scope.xCoord = canvasObject.x;
    $scope.yCoord = canvasObject.y;
    if (timeout) $timeout.cancel(timeout);
    timeout = $timeout(function () {
        $scope.$digest();
    });
}
```

The idea is that, every time the drag event runs, you trigger the digest, but if onDrag is called 10 times during a single digest, only one subsequent digest is queued.

Someone probably will have a better way to accomplish this, but this might get you started.